# British royal titles for regions not in Britain

Tags: british-empire, monarchy, titles

Royal titles for the British aristocracy seem to be associated with regions within Britain, particularly England; such as the Duke of Cambridge or the Princess of York.

Were there ever royal titles for other parts of the "Realm" that were not part of Britain, such as the Prince of Ireland or the Viscount of Virginia or the Duke of Saskatchewan?

Comment: Viscount Montgomery of El Alamein for one

Comment: Thanks for the edit...sorry, I couldn't help myself with my last comment :)

Comment: Elizabeth II is Queen of Australia (amongst her many other titles)

Comment: There's an enitre wikipedia article on [the titles of Queen Elizabeth II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_titles_and_honours_of_Queen_Elizabeth_II) which lists many places not in Britain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See Wikipedia, "Emperor of India":

> The title Emperor of India was used by the British monarchs during the British Raj in India from 1876 (see Royal Titles Act 1876) until 1948.

Remark. Interestingly, there was a British Empire but there was never a "British Emperor". S/he was only an Emperor/Empress of India. And British Queen/King.

Comment: I wonder why is this voted down? My answer is incorrect? Or it does not answer the question? Please consider adding some comment when you vote down.

Comment: One remarkable fact is that it was Queen Victoria who first took the title *Empress of India*, though she never visited the country.

Comment: If you were sent a High Court Writ of Summons in about 1950, it read something like: *George VI, by the Grace of God, of Great Britain, Ireland and the British Dominions beyond the Seas, King, Defender of the Faith, Emperor of India, COMMANDS that you attend the High Court at 10.00 o'clock in the forenoon of the 23rd day of September in the year of Our Lord 1950*.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_nobility):

> Outside the United Kingdom, the remaining Gaelic nobility of Ireland
>   continue informally to use their archaic provincial titles. As Ireland
>   was nominally under the overlordship of the English Crown for between
>   the 12th and 16th centuries, the Gaelic system coexisted with the
>   British system. A modern survivor of this coexistence is the Baron
>   Inchiquin, still referred to in Ireland as the Prince of Thomond. The
>   Prince of Thomond is one of three remaining claimants to the
>   non-existent, since the 12th century, so-called High Kingship of
>   Ireland, the others being The O'Neill, and the O'Conor Don.
>
> Chief of the Name was a clan designation which was effectively
>   terminated in 1601 with the collapse of the Gaelic order, and which,
>   through the policy of surrender and regrant, eliminated the role of a
>   chief in a clan or sept structure. Contemporary individuals today
>   designated or claiming a title of an Irish chief treat their title as
>   hereditary, whereas chiefs in the Gaelic order were nominated and
>   elected by a vote of their kinsmen. Modern "chiefs" of tribal septs
>   descend from provincial and regional kings with pedigrees beginning in
>   Late Antiquity, whereas Scottish chiefly lines arose well after the
>   formation of the Kingdom of Scotland, (with the exception of the Clann
>   Somhairle, or Clan Donald and Clan MacDougall, the two of royal
>   origins). The related Irish Mór ("Great") is sometimes used by the
>   dominant branches of the larger Irish dynasties to declare their
>   status as the leading princes of the blood, e.g. Ó Néill Mór, lit.
>   (The) Great O'Neill.
>
> Following the Norman invasion of Ireland several Hiberno-Norman
>   families adopted Gaelic customs, the most prominent being the De Burgh
>   dynasty and FitzGerald dynasty; their use of Galic customs did not
>   extend to their titles of nobility, as they continuously utilized
>   titles granted under English monarchy authority.